# Prevent .libPaths() in R from resolving symlinks

Tags: r, symlink

I have two *almost* identical systems.  I install software in system1 (a remote testing environment) in `/export/apps/` and then rsync the files to system2 in its `/export/apps`.  For file system reasons, `/export/` is really a symlink on each system. This usually works b/c for most many programs, any hard-baked paths contain the symlink and the file structure under the symlink is identical. So

**system1** : `/export/ -> /gpfs0/remote-test/export`

**system2** : `/export/ -> /gpfs0/export`

However, when I set `.libPaths` in R, R 'helpfully' resolves the symlinks.  I have a strong suspicion that when I rsync this to system2, those resolved symlinks are going to break the installed software.  E.g. (in R/4.0.0)

```
> .libPaths = .libPaths("/export/apps/opt/monocle3/1.0.0/")
> .libPaths()
[1] "/gpfs0/remote-test/export/apps/opt/monocle3/1.0.0"
[2] "/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/R/4.0.0-foss-2020a/lib64/R/library"
```

**QUESTION** :

Is there a way to prevent `.libPaths()` from resolving the symbolic link `/export/` to its full path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and installed the R package on our remote testing environment (system1) at `/gpfs0/remote-test/export/apps/opt/monocle3/1.0.0`.  It works (at least I can load the library) on system1.

I then rsync'd it the installed packages to `/gpfs0/export/apps/opt/monocle3/1.0.0` on system2 and it works there as well.

I did do some checking (i.e. `find . -name "*.so" -print | xargs -I var grep -in remote-test var`) of the shared libraries and the string `remote-test` was hard-baked into three of the shared libraries.

It appears that I got away with this this time (See user2554330's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71430679/4021436) for why it may not work in the future).  I was not hurt by any hard-baked paths as far as I can tell.  In this instance, I could can move `R` libraries around without breaking things.

Answer (score 2):

The `.libPaths()` function is pretty simple:

```
> .libPaths
function (new, include.site = TRUE) 
{
    if (!missing(new)) {
        new <- Sys.glob(path.expand(new))
        paths <- c(new, if (include.site) .Library.site, .Library)
        paths <- paths[dir.exists(paths)]
        .lib.loc <<- unique(normalizePath(paths, "/"))
    }
    else .lib.loc
}
```

Your symbolic links are being resolved in the call to `normalizePath(paths)` near the end.  So the answer to your question is "no, you can't tell `.libPaths()` not to resolve the symlink".

I suppose you could write your own version that didn't call `normalizePath()`, but that seems very risky:  R is likely assuming that it has happened.

I would also assume that using `rsync` to move installed packages from one location to another is likely to break something in packages that have complicated configurations.  Packages with `StagedInstall: FALSE` are allowed to assume this will never happen.

I think you're just going to have to install the packages again on `system2` to make sure they are configured properly for that system.